# Смена цвета меню JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на любое подменю, цвет меню менялся?

```js
var timers = [];

function showDropMenu(id) {
  stopTimer(id);
  document.all("dropMenu" + id).style.display = "block";
}

function hideDropMenu(id) {
  document.all("dropMenu" + id).style.display = "none";
}

function startTimer(id) {
  timers[id] = setTimeout("hideDropMenu(" + id + ")", 300);
}

function stopTimer(id) {
  clearTimeout(timers[id]);
}

function showMenu4(id) {
  document.all("newMenu" + id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
  .MenuItem {
  background-color: #F00000;
  color: white;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  border: 1px solid darkred;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: default;
}

.TopMenuItem {
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.TopMenuItem:hover {
  background-color: #FF1010;
}

.TopMenuItem44 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.DropMenu {
  width: 120px;
  top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 0.4em;
  padding-top: 0.4em;
  display: none;
}

.DropMenuItem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.9em;
  padding-top: 0.4em;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 1.5em;
}

.DropMenuItem:hover {
  background-color: #FF1010;
```

```html
<div class="MenuItem TopMenuItem" style="left: 0px" onmouseover="showDropMenu(1)" onmouseout="startTimer(1)" onClick="showMenu4(4)">Menu 1</div>
<div class="MenuItem TopMenuItem" style="left: 140px" onmouseover="showDropMenu(2)" onmouseout="startTimer(2)" onClick="showMenu4(4)">Menu 2</div>
<div class="MenuItem TopMenuItem" style="left: 280px" onmouseover="showDropMenu(3)" onmouseout="startTimer(3)" onClick="showMenu4(4)">Menu 3</div>

<div class="MenuItem TopMenuItem44" id="newMenu4" style="left: 420px" id="newMenu4">
  Menu4
</div>

<div class="MenuItem DropMenu" style="left: 10px" id="dropMenu1" onmouseover="stopTimer(1)" onmouseout="startTimer(1)">
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 1</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 2</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 3</div>
</div>

<div class="MenuItem DropMenu" style="left: 150px" id="dropMenu2" onmouseover="stopTimer(2)" onmouseout="startTimer(2)">
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 1</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showDropMenu(22)" onmouseout="startTimer(22)">subMenu 2</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 3</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 4</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 5</div>
</div>

<div class="MenuItem DropMenu" style="left: 290px" id="dropMenu3" onmouseover="stopTimer(3)" onmouseout="startTimer(3)">
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 1</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 2</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 3</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 4</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 5</div>
</div>

<div class="MenuItem DropMenu" style="left: 220px; top: 100px" id="dropMenu22" onmouseover="stopTimer(22); stopTimer(2)" onmouseout="startTimer(22)">
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 2.1</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem" onmouseover="showDropMenu(222)" onmouseout="startTimer(222)" onClick="showMenu4(4)">subMenu 2.2</div>
</div>

<div class="MenuItem DropMenu" style="left: 270px; top: 160px" id="dropMenu222" onmouseover="stopTimer(222); stopTimer(22); stopTimer(2)" onmouseout="startTimer(222)">
  <div class="DropMenuItem">subMenu 2.2.1</div>
  <div class="DropMenuItem">subMenu 2.2.2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Менялся и оставался таким...? Изменялся в момент клика?

Comment: Опиши нормально, подробно, какого желаемого результата хочется добиться

Comment: Переделывайте разметку, чтобы подменю находились внутри своих родительских меню элементов. С Вашими `left` и `top` Вы копаете себе яму.

Comment: чтобы при клике в любом подменю, менялся цвет таблицы, и оставался таким

Comment: Ну ты же уже умеешь открывать `меню4` по клику , что тебе мешает тем же методом изменять цвет меню?

Comment: заполните массив нужными цветами типа ["#cc2299","red","orange"] а затем при каждом выборе устанавливайте случайный цвет + проверка на !=